# EXTJS Radio Group background colour is white

Tags: extjs, radio-button, radio-group

I am attempting to set the background colour of my radio group as . However the background colour remains white for the code below:

```
xtype: 'radiogroup',
hideLabel: true,
id: 'rtse1',
disabled: true,
width: 255,
bodyStyle: 'background-color: #DDE5E9;',
style: 'padding-left:85px',
items: [
   {boxLabel: 'Static', name: 'rb-auto17', inputValue: 'Y', checked: true},
   {boxLabel: 'Default', name: 'rb-auto17', inputValue: 'N'}
]
```

Is there a way to fix this problem. Your help is kindly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

`bodyStyle` is not a config for a radio group, it doesn't extend panel. Instead, you should just set the `style` config, or a `cls` property and do it via css.

Answer (score 0):

`style` applied to `radiogroup` wasn't applied correctly.
So I've applied `cls` (as @EvanTrimboli suggested)

```
cls: 'custom_group'
```

And in css file:

```
.custom_group .x-panel-body{
    background-color: #DDE5E9;
}
```